# How do I know the right data format for different LLMs finetuning？

Tags: nlp, large-language-model

I have seen people use different data formats to fine-tune different LLMs. For example, the following format can be used for Llama-2:

```
  {
    "instruction": "",
    "input": "",
    "output": ""
  }
```

and sometimes the format below is used for chatglm2-6b:

```
   {
    "content": "",
    "summary": ""
  }
```

Is it related to what format was used for pre-training or actually both can be used for different llms, how do I organize my custom data if I want to fine-tune a llm?